# How to force LDAP to use a secondary local IP Address in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, ldap, ip-address, directoryentry

I need to access a remote LDAP server behind a firewall (using C#/.NET) for user authentication.

The firewall at the remote site is set to allow a specific IP address, but it *is not* the primary IP Address on the server i.e. by default, the connection to the remote LDAP server would use the primary IP.

*How do you force LDAP to use a secondary IP Address in .NET?*

---

I am specifically using the `System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry` and `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext` classes, but there isn't obvious way I could see to control the local end point.

This is how I would bind to a local IP address using a TcpClient:

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

IPEndPoint localEndpoint = ...get relevant local ip address that needs to connect
TcpClient tcp = new TcpClient( localEndpoint );
...do stuff with tcp client
```

*NB: The primary IP address of the server cannot be changed in this instance.*

*PS: While I use the word "bind" here to mean binding to a **local end point**, LDAP uses the word "bind" for connecting/authenticating to the directory.*

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to PInvoke the ldap_* functions in wldap32.dll.  It looks like the LDAP_OPT_SOCKET_BIND_ADDRESSES option in [Session Options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367019%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) will let you control which local endpoint to use.  The System.DirectoryServices.Protocols is the managed version of this API, but I don't see a corresponding property in [LdapSessionOptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.directoryservices.protocols.ldapsessionoptions_members%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

This works for me:

```
class LDAPConnection : IDisposable
{
    public static bool IsValidCredentials(string domain, string localAddress, 
                       string usernameDomain, string username, SecureString password)
    {
        try
        {
            using (LDAPConnection ldapConnection = 
                       new LDAPConnection(domain, LDAP_PORT, localAddress))
            {
                ldapConnection.Bind(usernameDomain, username, password);
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    protected IntPtr _ld;
    protected List<IntPtr> _stringPointers;

    public LDAPConnection(string hostname, uint port, params string[] localAddresses)
    {
        _stringPointers = new List<IntPtr>();

        _ld = LdapInit(hostname, port);
        LdapSetOption(_ld, LDAP_OPT_VERSION, LDAP_VERSION3);

        if (localAddresses != null && localAddresses.Length > 0)
        {
            string addr = string.Join(" ", localAddresses);
            IntPtr pStr = LdapSetOption(_ld, LDAP_OPT_SOCKET_BIND_ADDRESSES, addr);
            _stringPointers.Add(pStr);
        }
    }

    public void Bind(string domain, string username, SecureString password)
    {
        LdapBind(_ld, domain, username, password);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_ld != NULL) ldap_unbind_s(_ld);
        foreach (IntPtr pString in _stringPointers)
        {
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pString);
        }
    }

    [DllImport("wldap32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern uint LdapGetLastError();

    [DllImport("wldap32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    protected static extern IntPtr ldap_init(string HostName, uint PortNumber);

    //caller must call ldap_unbind or ldap_unbind_s on the return value
    public static IntPtr LdapInit(string hostname, uint port)
    {
        IntPtr ld = ldap_init(hostname, port);
        if (ld == NULL)
        {
            throw new Exception("LDAP Error: " + LdapGetLastError());
        }
        return ld;
    }

    [DllImport("wldap32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern uint ldap_unbind_s(IntPtr ld);

    [DllImport("wldap32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern uint ldap_set_option(IntPtr ld, uint option, ref IntPtr invalue);

    [DllImport("wldap32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern uint ldap_set_option(IntPtr ld, uint option, ref uint invalue);

    //caller must free IntPtr after calling ldap_unbind_s
    public static IntPtr LdapSetOption(IntPtr ld, uint option, string invalue)
    {
        IntPtr pString = Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni(invalue);
        bool exception = true;

        try
        {
            uint errorCode = ldap_set_option(ld, option, ref pString);
            if (errorCode != LDAP_SUCCESS)
            {
                throw new Exception("LDAP Error: " + errorCode);
            }
            exception = false;
            return pString;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (exception && pString != NULL)
            {
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pString);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void LdapSetOption(IntPtr ld, uint option, uint invalue)
    {
        uint errorCode = ldap_set_option(ld, option, ref invalue);
        if (errorCode != LDAP_SUCCESS)
        {
            throw new Exception("LDAP Error: " + errorCode);
        }
    }

    [DllImport("wldap32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    protected static extern uint ldap_bind_s(IntPtr ld, IntPtr dn, IntPtr cred, uint method);

    public static void LdapBind(IntPtr ld, string domain, 
                                string username, SecureString password)
    {
        IntPtr cred = SEC_WINNT_AUTH_IDENTITY.GetUnicode(username, password, domain);
        try
        {
            uint errorCode = ldap_bind_s(ld, NULL, cred, LDAP_AUTH_NEGOTIATE);
            if (errorCode != LDAP_SUCCESS)
            {
                throw new Exception("LDAP Error: " + errorCode);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (cred != NULL) SEC_WINNT_AUTH_IDENTITY.Free(cred);
        }
    }

    public const uint LDAP_PORT = 389;
    public const uint LDAP_VERSION3 = 3;
    public const uint LDAP_SUCCESS = 0;
    public const uint LDAP_OPT_VERSION = 0x11;
    public const uint LDAP_OPT_SOCKET_BIND_ADDRESSES = 0x44;
    public const uint LDAP_AUTH_NEGOTIATE = 0x486;
    public static readonly IntPtr NULL = IntPtr.Zero;
    public const uint SEC_WINNT_AUTH_IDENTITY_ANSI = 1;
    public const uint SEC_WINNT_AUTH_IDENTITY_UNICODE = 2;

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct SEC_WINNT_AUTH_IDENTITY
    {
        public IntPtr User;
        public int UserLength;
        public IntPtr Domain;
        public int DomainLength;
        public IntPtr Password;
        public int PasswordLength;
        public uint Flags;

        public static IntPtr GetUnicode(string username, 
                                        SecureString password, string domain)
        {
            SEC_WINNT_AUTH_IDENTITY swai = new SEC_WINNT_AUTH_IDENTITY();
            bool exception = true;
            try
            {
                swai.User = Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni(username);
                swai.UserLength = username.Length;
                swai.Domain = Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni(domain);
                swai.DomainLength = domain.Length;
                swai.Password = Marshal.SecureStringToGlobalAllocUnicode(password);
                swai.PasswordLength = password.Length;
                swai.Flags = SEC_WINNT_AUTH_IDENTITY_UNICODE;

                IntPtr pSwai = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(swai));
                try
                {
                    Marshal.StructureToPtr(swai, pSwai, false);
                    exception = false;
                    return pSwai;
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (exception && pSwai != NULL)
                    {
                        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pSwai);
                    }
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (exception)
                {
                    if (swai.User != NULL) Marshal.FreeHGlobal(swai.User);
                    if (swai.Domain != NULL) Marshal.FreeHGlobal(swai.Domain);
                    if (swai.Password != NULL)
                    {
                        Marshal.ZeroFreeGlobalAllocUnicode(swai.Password);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public static void Free(IntPtr pSwai)
        {
            SEC_WINNT_AUTH_IDENTITY swai = 
                (SEC_WINNT_AUTH_IDENTITY)Marshal.PtrToStructure(
                    pSwai, typeof(SEC_WINNT_AUTH_IDENTITY));
            if (swai.Flags == SEC_WINNT_AUTH_IDENTITY_ANSI)
            {
                Marshal.ZeroFreeGlobalAllocAnsi(swai.Password);
            }
            else
            {
                Marshal.ZeroFreeGlobalAllocUnicode(swai.Password);
            }
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(swai.Domain);
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(swai.User);
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pSwai);
        }
    }
```

Example usage:

```
LDAPConnection.IsValidCredentials("leaf.domain.com", "10.0.0.1", "leaf", 
    "myusername", password);
```

Comment: Thanks @Hall72215, but you've specified how to connect to a _remote server_ endpoint. This example will use the primary IP address of the client machine. What I have asked for is how to use a secondary IP address on the client machine to connect to the remote machine.

Comment: @DaveTransom Interesting question, I haven't seen anything that would allow you to set this.  To be fair, you referred to both the client and the LDAP server as servers, so it was hard to tell that's what you were asking.

Comment: @DaveTransom I edited the answer to address your question.  I haven't used this API so I don't have code, but I can figure it out if you still need it.

Comment: Wow, that's a significant edit and looks promising - I'll investigate that a bit more and get back once time permits, cheers!